# PHP htmlentities not working? output is?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store some data in my MySQL database.
When I try to input special characters and even foreign characters like ø or звяф, I want them to be stored as html entities (like ő)

I thought it's supersimple, just use htmlentities(), but when I store data, I am getting nothing but ???? in the database.

Any ideas?

Here is the code I use right now:

```
$sqlOrder="INSERT INTO data (
        bad, cname, lor
    )
    VALUES (
        '".htmlentities($b->getBad(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')."', '".htmlentities($b->getCName(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')."', '".htmlentities($b->getLor(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')."'
    )";
```

As said, the result in the database is ????????? for any special characters such as кршуцкыя or æåø.

Comment: Your DB collation is also utf8? `$b->getBad()` is utf8? Tried `utf8_encode();`? Update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the data collation of your database?  By default, most MySQL installs set `latin1_swedish_ci` instead of `utf8_general_ci` for newly created databases.

Change the collation of the database & try again.

```
ALTER DATABASE [name of your database] CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

If this is a specific table, the collation can be changed as so:

```
ALTER TABLE [name of your table] CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

And if it is a specific column in a table:

```
ALTER TABLE [name of your table] MODIFY [name of your column] [other settings] CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Or perhaps you could export the current database, create a new database with this command & reimport the data:

```
CREATE DATABASE [name of your database] CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```